# Configuration error while executing cucumber-jvm + testNG?

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, cucumber-jvm

I am using cucumber-jvm + testNg + Maven to run my test cases . My runner class would look like this

```
   @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
   @Cucumber.Options(
       format={"pretty", "json:target/report.json"},
       features = "classpath:cucumber/Login.feature",   
       glue = "stepDefinitions",
       tags="@login,@AB,@close"

       )
  public class RunCukesTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{  }
```

Maven command to execute test cases .

```
 mvn test
```

And I am getting this error

```
      Configuring TestNG with:  org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@3eec1a
      Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.437 sec <<< FAILURE!
      run_cukes(runner.RunCukesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.015 sec  <<< FAILURE!
      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
      at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.<init>  (TestNGCucumberRunner.java:29)
      at Cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.run_cukes(AbstractTestNGCucumber          Tests.java:14)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelpe       r.java:200)
     at Cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.run(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your cucumber dependency versions are not compatible with your testng dependency versions, or you have some other dependency conflict going on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove @RunWith(Cucumber.class) - from junit4
2. import cucumber options from  testng **import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;**

Refer this documentation [Link](https://qaautomation.expert/2021/06/22/integration-of-cucumber-with-selenium-and-testng/) for more